# FB.getLoginStatus response.status always connected?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I am developing an app using apache cordova/phonegap. My problem is, when a user has logged out facebook from native facebook app, in my app the status is always `connected` when I call `FB.getLoginStatus`. What am doing wrong? How can I detect if a user has logged out from facebook native app?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>yourFREEtree</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>


<div id="data">loading ...</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<!-- cordova -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>

<!-- facebook js sdk -->
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>

<script>

<!-- These are the notifications that are displayed to the user through pop-ups if the above JS files does not exist in the same directory-->

if ((typeof cordova == 'undefined') && (typeof Cordova == 'undefined')) alert('Cordova variable does not exist. Check that you have included cordova.js correctly');
if (typeof CDV == 'undefined') alert('CDV variable does not exist. Check that you have included cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js correctly');
if (typeof FB == 'undefined') alert('FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.');


FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
//alert('auth.logout '+response.status);
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
//alert('auth.sessionChange '+response.status);
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
        alert(response.status);         
        //alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);
    }, true);
});


document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                     try {
                     //alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                     FB.init({ appId: "{MYAPPID HERE}", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
                     document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
                     } catch (e) {
                     alert(e);
                     }
                     }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connect using Facebook Login into your Phonegap App, a facebook session is stored "inside" your phonegap app data space. It is possible due the Facebook API that you use when you call FB.login function. I'll give you two scenarios so that you can understand better:

- Phonegap app without call Facebook Login and Facebook APP logged IN:
   FB.getLoginStatus status returns unknown
- Phonegap app after call Facebook Login and Facebook APP not logged IN:             FB.getLoginStatus status returns connected.

You can try deleting your Phonegap app data and you'll see that the status is connected no more.